# Selecting/Deleting duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the below table `CatItemLink` with the records in it:

```
ID                                      CatID                                   ItemID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADBFBEFE-11F4-4CF0-A889-BBC9358CCF57    A411277E-0873-4323-B016-63F4DFA664C2    B66A47DF-A0E3-4D41-88E9-0B0CB27085D7
->E212A458-E5E2-4D77-B618-425082CFD8D2  A411277E-0873-4323-B016-63F4DFA664C2    B66A47DF-A0E3-4D41-88E9-0B0CB27085D7

D071B1C1-7296-4BCA-8AD3-8495704BF679    A411277E-0873-4323-B016-63F4DFA664C2    E288327C-15BF-4B01-BD37-0B6AD5365966
->B4F59516-2D85-4E2A-8FE4-3EDA27C3DA4F  A411277E-0873-4323-B016-63F4DFA664C2    E288327C-15BF-4B01-BD37-0B6AD5365966
->F3FB6BA5-79EC-4FC5-899E-24FA9F8DFF25  A411277E-0873-4323-B016-63F4DFA664C2    E288327C-15BF-4B01-BD37-0B6AD5365966

CF3FBD01-4445-4A72-AD1A-BF397970AEFC    BFB76F3D-4F06-4200-925D-1968666741A3    E288327C-15BF-4B01-BD37-0B6AD5365966
```

`ID` is a primary key. [`CatID`,`ItemID`] should have been a unique index, but the DBO did not specify that index. How to delete/select the records marked with `->` meaning there will be only one `ItemID` per `CatID`.
(`ItemID` can be found with different `CatID` and this is ok).

I have a solution that uses `SET ROWCOUNT` but I want to have an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
( 
  SELECT ID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY CatID, ItemID ORDER BY ID)
  FROM dbo.CatItemLink
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID AS IDsToDelete
FROM  (SELECT ID, Row_number() OVER (partition BY catid, itemid ORDER BY id) AS Dup
       FROM   CatItemLink ) a
WHERE  dup > 1
```

I think this will select what you want. This will partition the table by the CatID and ItemID columns, and effectively assign each row a rank (i.e. if there are duplicates, it'll get assigned a rank higher than 1).

Comment: The problem is that your query returns rows where `CatID` contains only 1 `ItemID` (which is not what I want). this `ItemID` has duplicates in other `CatID`

Comment: @kobik can you show which row is returned by this query that shouldn't be? *Every* row contains only one `ItemID`, doesn't it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, every row *should* contain a unique (`CatID`, `ItemID`). the row that returned was the same as the last row (In reality I have much more rows). I executed your CTE query by mistake and the data was deleted so I can't repro :/ There was only 1 anomaly. trying to repro again...

Comment: The query identifies the rows to *delete* not the rows to *keep*. Of course you may see the same row twice if the table originally had three such rows. Unless you only want to delete one duplicate at a time, this is exactly how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand `The query identifies the rows to delete not the rows to keep`: I realize that, and as I said, I executed the query by mistake. I must have seen the same row ID twice.

Comment: @Bridge, Thank you for your answer. I'm not a CTE fan, but Aaron did answer first with the same solution, so I have to accept his answer.

Comment: No problem - I've edited my original answer so you get the rows you wanted to delete rather than the ones to keep if you wanted it!

Comment: @Bridge, I think you meant the opposite. Your initial query was fine, and in fact returned the row to **delete**.

Comment: I thought that was what you were after! I've changed it back :-)